# Apollo client.query not fetching?

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to use `client.query` to make API calls outside of a React component using `@apollo/client`. However, `client.query` seems to not be making any requests to my API server at all, and simply hanging without throwing any errors either. See below.

```js
const refreshToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("refresh");
const client = getApolloClient();

const { data } = await client.query<RefreshQuery, RefreshQueryVariables>({
  query: RefreshDocument, // DocumentNode generated by graphql-codegen
  variables: { refreshToken },
});

console.log(data) // Never logs anything.
```

Here's my instantiation of the Apollo Client.

```js
let client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>;
export const getApolloClient = (): ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> => {
  if (!client) {
    client = new ApolloClient({
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      link: link ?? undefined, // link is of type ApolloLink from apollo-upload-client
      connectToDevTools: true,
      defaultOptions: {
        query: { errorPolicy: "all", fetchPolicy: "network-only" },
      },
    });
  }
  return client;
};
```

Wrapping `client.query` inside a `trycatch` also does not yield any errors whatsoever. Using hooks like `useQuery` and `useMutation` works perfectly fine.

What's going on here, and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Have you tried using state to see if the async components are able to initialize a loading status? This seems to be set up correctly so it's likely something upstream that isn't passing down the data.